# Problem with PDF Output (creating bible with xsl-fo and xml)

Tags: xml, pdf, output, xsl-fo

Good day,
first: I am a beginner about what I want to ask:

I've been trying XSL-FO for some time, but I usually reach my limits.
I am working on a bible and also using XML. But now there are design problems, so from the PDF.

I would like the PDF to have the following output:
http://www.freie-bibel.de/official/projekt/hag2latex8.png
It latex of course, but output should be similar.
Especially the verses should be on the outside.
The footnotes fall out.

However, I am not quite succeeding.
For editing the files you can look here:
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nb9PtDi/95

Does anyone have any ideas and can help me?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example that uses AH Formatter `fo:float` extension. The prefix `axf:` means AH Formatter extension. ( `xmlns:axf="http://www.antennahouse.com/names/XSL/Extensions"` )

```xml
  <xsl:template match="VERSE">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="VERSE/text()">
    <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::node()) and not(parent::*/@vnumber = 1)">
      <fo:float axf:float-x="column-outside" axf:float-offset-x="-2em">
        <fo:block-container width="2em" top="-1lh">
          <fo:block line-height.conditionality="discard" text-align="center" text-align-last="center" padding-top="-1lh">
            <fo:inline font-weight="bold" font-size="0.9em">
              <xsl:value-of select="parent::*/@vnumber"/>
            </fo:inline>
          </fo:block>
        </fo:block-container>
      </fo:float>
    </xsl:if>
    <fo:inline font-style="{$Schriftschnitt}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </fo:inline>
  </xsl:template>
```

The screen shot:

[image: AH Formatter GUI]

Comment: Thanks for the quick help!
I'm currently working with Apache FOP 2.6 and unfortunately there are only errors or the process is not executed due to "axf:".
Here is the link:
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nb9PtDi/101
I have put xmlns:axf="http://www.antennahouse.com/names/XSL/Extensions to stylesheet, but it shows me Error (see the link)

with FOP 2.6 via CMD many JAVA errors come up.
Then changed  the tags 
<fo:float to <xsl:float, but then it shows me on the PDF only the Chapter Numbers.

AH Formatter I have to try. Many, many thanks already!
Greetings

Comment: Yes, unfortunately FOP 2.6 does not have fo:float extensions. To get this formatting result needs AH Formatter.

Comment: Yes, I also found out later that there is no other way. However, AH Formatter seems to be a bit too expensive for my use and case, yet I thank you for the great help. All the best!

Comment: FOP's error messages about `axf:*` properties is arguably a bug. https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#xsl-namespace includes "An element from the XSL namespace may have any attribute not from the XSL namespace, provided that the expanded-name of the attribute has a non-null namespace URI...Thus, an XSL processor is always free to ignore such attributes, and must ignore such attributes without giving an error if it does not recognize the namespace URI." Unfortunately, just dropping the unrecognised properties doesn't get you any closer to the result that you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AH Formatter, you could put the verse number in an `fo:change-bar-begin` (see https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-ext.html#fo.change-bar-begin) and specify `change-bar-placement="alternate"` to get the correct positions (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#change-bar-placement).

I don't know if John 11:35 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus_wept) is as short in German, but this technique would have trouble with two verse numbers on one line. How does the LaTeX version handle that?

(With AH Formatter, you could also do that dropped chapter number (see https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-ext.html#DropCapitals), though if it is just a number and not the initial letter of a word, you could also do it with an `fo:float`.)